# Looping thru a text file and trying to create a nested dictionary but the dictionary only prints last loop iteration not full loop nested together

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I am trying to create a nested dictionary from some for loops. If my code is positioned like this:

```
    for figure in problem.figures:

        for object in problem.figures[figure].objects:
            attribute_dict_A = {}
            nested_dict = {}

            for k, v in problem.figures[figure].objects[object].attributes.items():
                attribute_dict_A[k] = v
                attribute_dict_A.update({'object': object})

                nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A

        print(nested_dict)
```

Then the output shows the entire loop iterated through as below:

> {'A': {'shape': 'square', 'object': 'a', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'B': {'shape': 'square', 'object': 'b', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'C': {'shape': 'square', 'object': 'c', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'1': {'shape': 'pentagon', 'object': 'd', 'fill': 'yes', 'size':
>   'very large'}}
>
> {'2': {'shape': 'square', 'object': 'e', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'3': {'shape': 'triangle', 'object': 'f', 'fill': 'yes', 'size':
>   'very large'}}
>
> {'4': {'shape': 'pac-man', 'object': 'g', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'5': {'shape': 'star', 'object': 'h', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}
>
> {'6': {'shape': 'heart', 'object': 'i', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}

But if my code is properly indented (see the `'print(nested_dict)'`) indentation then it only prints the last iteration of the loop.

**How can I the loop to iterate and also store everything I need?**

```
for figure in problem.figures:

        for object in problem.figures[figure].objects:
            attribute_dict_A = {}
            nested_dict = {}

            for k, v in problem.figures[figure].objects[object].attributes.items():
                attribute_dict_A[k] = v
                attribute_dict_A.update({'object': object})

                nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A

print(nested_dict)
```

My final output is coming like this:

> {'6': {'shape': 'heart', 'object': 'i', 'fill': 'yes', 'size': 'very
>   large'}}

EDIT----

I updated my code to this but I am still not getting the result I need. It seems to be overriding my dictionary each time it iterates through the loop.

```
nested_dict = {}
attribute_dict = {}

    for figure in problem.figures:

        for object in problem.figures[figure].objects:



            for k, v in problem.figures[figure].objects[object].attributes.items():
                attribute_dict[k] = v
                attribute_dict.update({'object': object})

        nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict

    pprint(nested_dict)
```

Here is a sample of the text file I am looping through:

The capital A is the figure, the lower case a is the object, the k,v are the attribute pair

```
A
    a
        shape:circle
        size:very large
        fill:no
    b
        shape:plus
        size:small
        fill:yes
        angle:0
       inside:a
B
    c
        shape:circle
        size:very large
        fill:no
    d
        shape:plus
        size:small
        fill:yes
        angle:0
        inside:c
C
    e
        shape:circle
        size:very large
        fill:no
    f
        shape:plus
        size:small
        fill:yes
        angle:0
        inside:e
```

Comment: Fix the position of declaring `nested_dict`, then good things happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterating then creating a dictionary so every time of iteration, new empty dict is created so move `nested_dict` out of the loop:

```
nested_dict = {}
for figure in problem.figures:

        for object in problem.figures[figure].objects:
            attribute_dict_A = {}

            for k, v in problem.figures[figure].objects[object].attributes.items():
                attribute_dict_A[k] = v
                attribute_dict_A.update({'object': object})

                nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A

print(nested_dict)
```

Btw maybe should reposition the `attribute_dict_A` too:

```
attribute_dict_A = {}
nested_dict = {}
for figure in problem.figures:

        for object in problem.figures[figure].objects:

            for k, v in problem.figures[figure].objects[object].attributes.items():
                attribute_dict_A[k] = v
                attribute_dict_A.update({'object': object})

                nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A

print(nested_dict)
```

Comment: `nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A` seems to indicate, that `attribute_dict_A = {}` was where it needs to be. Otherwise `attribute_dict_A` will just keep growing. If anything th assignment `nested_dict[figure] = attribute_dict_A` can be moved up one level of nesting

Comment: @MTTI Ok thanks, anyways o gave two solutions then maybe one will work for him

Comment: Thanks u9 forward- i updated my code and added more context. I am still a little stuck.

Comment: @U9-Forward added tag